# How to declare a method used for NSMenuItem with no existing classes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sdl-2

I'm trying to create a typical simple macOS menu for my otherwise pure C project and this is the only Objective-C code I have in it, I didn't create any classes or anything:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

- (void)method_new_file:(id)sender { new_flag = 1; }

void mac_menu_file_init()
{
    NSMenu      *currentMenu;
    NSMenuItem  *menuItem;

    currentMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"File"];   // set menu name

    [currentMenu addItemWithTitle:@"New..." action:@selector(method_new_file:)  keyEquivalent:@"n"];

    // Put menu into the menubar and give up our references to the objects
    menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
    [menuItem setSubmenu:currentMenu];
    [[NSApp mainMenu] insertItem:menuItem atIndex:1];
    [currentMenu release];
    [menuItem release];
}
```

The problem is obvious, I'm "missing a context for method declaration" for `method_new_file`, but where do I go from here? I just want that method to be called whenever I click the menu entry, but for that to happen it must be part of something, but what? Based on code and answers I've seen I tried the following:

```
@interface My_Actions : NSApplication
@end

@implementation My_Actions

- (void)method_new_file:(id)sender { new_flag = 1; }

@end
```

and other things like it, to no avail, the menu entry remains hopelessly grayed out and I don't know what else to try.

Comment: If your code is "otherwise pure C", do you have an application object? Are you running the main event loop? Are you using some C-based GUI wrapper toolkit?

Comment: I use SDL2, other than that I didn't define any application object (SDL2 might have). So it's just a typical SDL2 program and at the beginning of the execution I run the function posted above. It seems that this is what SDL2 does in that regard: https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/7aff227a2dfb3e51a30d0faf49e903a0ad885f0c/src/video/cocoa/SDL_cocoaevents.m#L36

Comment: why dont u convert the ObjC code to C instead?

Comment: @GeneCode I'd love to but how? Isn't Objective C or Swift required for Cocoa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would hope that SDL2 would provide a mechanism for adding menu items.

If it doesn't, you need an object to target with your menu item. In Objective-C, classes are also objects (instances of their meta-class) and they're conveniently static in lifetime. So, you could so something like:

```
@interface MyMenuTarget : NSObject
@end

@implementation MyMenuTarget
+ (void) openNewFile:(id)sender
{
    new_flag = 1;
}
@end
```

Notice the `+` on the method declaration. That means the method is a class method, not an instance method. But a class method is just a method of the class object (compared to an instance method which is a method of an instance of the class).

And then, where you create the menu item, you should set the target to this class:

```
menuItem = [currentMenu addItemWithTitle:@"New..." action:@selector(openNewFile:)  keyEquivalent:@"n"];
menuItem.target = [MyMenuTarget class];
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! And sadly no, SDL provides no way of creating menus, which seems like a rather big oversight.